# Mathematics - Inventory Control Function

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, integral

when i read an inventory book, i saw a function. But i don't really know how to solve it in mathematics. I need your help. 
Best wishes and thanks for helping!!!
[image]

---

when i read an inventory book, i saw they made a relationship between normal distribution and loss function. If i dont use this relationship, i can't solve the problem. So i need your help. Best wishes for you!!!
[image]
[image]

---

As u see, we will get this function

[image]
[image]

---

And this is the result if we follow the function
[image]

Comment: That is just the cumulative density function of a standard normal distribution. It has been solved for you on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) $F(x)\;=\;\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\;=\; \frac12\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$

Comment: I am sorry but If i got mean (μ) is 10 and the standard deviation (σ) is sqrt(10). How can i define integral from 9 until 14. When i don't know how to calculate integral erf(x−μ/√σ2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for the formula you quoted is $F(x)\;=\frac12\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$ because the mean ($\mu$) is zero, and the standard deviation ($\sigma$) is 1. The error function (erf) is a standard function defined as an infinite sum (or an integral) and included in many software packages, so, it is no different than any other function, like sine or hyperbolic tangent in the way it is used. You do not need to know anything about it, either, all you need to do in any statistical package is use the cumulative standard normal distribution. For your problem, now that you relate it, in Excel you would use =NORM.DIST(x,10,SQRT(10),TRUE) for whatever value you wish to calculate for x. To solve this for the integral from 9 to 14 you simply use

=NORM.DIST(14,10,SQRT(10),TRUE)-NORM.DIST(9,10,SQRT(10),TRUE),

or the equivalent in any statistical program you choose to use.

**Edit:** In case you are wondering what the error function is, which you actually don't have to know to use $F(x)$ for a normal distribution, it is a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) whose plot is in blue
[image]
However, erf$(x)$ has a limiting slope at $x=0$ of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}$. To put it into standard sigmoid form, i.e., one that has a limit of $-1$ as $x\to -\infty$, a slope of 1 as $x\to 0$ and 1 as $x\to \infty$ one uses the orange curve above.

The primary definition of the error function is from the infinite sum, which is convergent for $k$ sufficiently large.

$$\text{erf}(z)=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k z^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1) k!}$$

The error function has a zillion properties, if you want to see all (239) of them go to the [Wolfram function site](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erf/) which includes 4 different integral expressions one of which is

$$\text{erf}(z)=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_0^z e^{-t^2} \, dt.$$

The cumulative standard normal distribution (i.e., CDF of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ with mean zero and standard deviation of 1) is defined as $F(x)\;=\frac12\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$, which adds 1 to a not standard form sigmoid error function and then takes half of that to make a curve that goes from $p=0$ as $x$ goes to negative infinity to $p=1$ at infinity. That looks like this graphically:

[image]

As for the use of the non-standard sigmoid curve form of the error function, i.e., $\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, that is done so that the slope of the CDF at $x=0$ becomes $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$, that in turn is the magnitude of the standard normal distribution that allows its integral (CDF) to have $p=\dfrac{1}{2}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Tks Mr.Carl, i got it.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you,you should consider upvoting it and selecting it!

Comment: Thank-you @kjetilbhalvorsen . It is discouraging when actual answers are not voted on. Looking back on my answers, and voting on them, newbies rarely vote, and the votes I do get are usually on only the most complicated points that experts find confusing. I think that is just because newbies do not know how to use the site, or do not have voting privileges. For the newbie above, he does not have a 15 reputation so he cannot upvote. Also, the question he originally asked bears no relationship to what is currently displayed.

Comment: I am sr Mr. Carl. I am a newbie and try to upvote for u many times but i can't. Maybe my account don't be allowed for upvoting. Btw, thank you very much, your answer is useful.

Comment: Recently, i post a new way to solve the problem, which i read in the book. I just wanna share my knowledge to you and hope u can use it. Have a nice day, mah master!

Comment: You are most welcome. When you have new problem, you should make a new question for it so that you do not overwrite the old one. That way, you will eventually get enough reputation points to be able to vote.